# How do I extract from a non-transactional DB those examples satisfying rules in 'arules' r package format?

Tags: r, xml, subset, arules, pmml

I have conducted an analysis on my database using the R package 'RKEEL'. Specifically, I have used the function NICGAR_A which applies an Association Rule Based-on Niche Genetic Algorithm. As a result I obtain a set of ~10 rules which explain my whole dataset. Since the obtained rules are in arules package and NICGAR_A() does not use a transactional database I do not know how to select individuals/examples of my database satisfying these rules.

I have tried to make subset() introducing each range variable included in each rule. However I would like to automatize the process.

The obtained rules are in arules package format. And I have exported also in xml format using write.PMML.

Would you mind helping me with that issue? If you need further specific information regarding the problem, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check the format of my generated rules in xml format.
http://www.dmg.org/pmml/v4-3/pmml-4-3.xsd">2018-03-26 16:04:57